# Facebook browser

Tags: facebook

I was thinking how to write a program which can log me to Facebook and collect the latest status updates of my friends to a linked list. Can this be done for example by PHP or Python without learning Facebook api or do I need to learn that first?

Comment: *Can this be done for example by PHP or Python* --> yes. *without learning Facebook api or do I need to learn that first* --> yes, learn it first

Comment: Hi Jaska, first I'd recommend you get familiar with the Facebook API they provide free of charge. It's simple to use and ultimately you'll be able to access things much easier than scraping plain old HTML.

Comment: Why would you want to get facebook data without using their API, which is built specifically to get facebook data?

Comment: I was wondering if it would be faster to make a parser on my own as I know some PHP but maybe it is faster to learn the API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

probably scraping their mobile site seem the easiest solution in that case

http://m.facebook.com/

python seem the best language to deal with it

Comment: please note that you are heavily dependent on facebook not changing the mobile website too much. Whereas the api is hopefully more fixed or properly versioned.

Answer (score 0):

To get your friends’ RSS status feed:

1. Sign into Facebook
2. Go to http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?friends
3. Copy the link to “My Friends’ Notes” on the right hand side
4. Replace “friends_notes” with “friends_status”

This will give you an RSS feed of all of your friend's statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly do it using Php but it would be really dirty.
The right way is to use the Facebook API.